# Overriding automatically assigned values for gradient color scales in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset suffering from overplotting. To simplify I'm showing the mean value of the points in a certain area with the help of a stat_summary plot. My problem is that the color scale adjusts to the range of values within each plot, making the comparison trickier.

My example below demonstrates that the points in the bottom left corner of p1 ranges between ~50 - ~148 (dark green to yellow). When computing the mean in the stat_summary plot, p2, I want it to end up as a light green hexagons since the mean should be ~100. However, the color scale shifts rendering the bottom left hexagon blue and magenta.

How do I override the automatic assignment of colors? I have tried to set manual breaks and values, but since I'm using a logarithmic color scale it's tricky to estimate the exact value of the different colors. Is there a way to "copy paste" the color scale and assigned values from p1 to p2?

reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)  
  
x = c(3, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 4, 21, 2, 3, 54, 1, 2, 1, 5, 254)
y = c(1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 2.50, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 8.00, 1.00, 2.00, 4.20, 1.00, 1.00, 4.91, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 2.50, 42.33)
z = c(71, 265, 430, 110, 80, 87, 100, 174, 111, 102, 157, 118, 267, 133, 102, 435, 107, 72, 123, 115)

df2 <- data.frame(x,y,z)

p1 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = z), size = 5) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(name = "z",colours = colorRampPalette(c("dark green", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "purple", "blue"))(100), trans = "log")

print(p1)

p2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x, y, z = z)) + 
  stat_summary_hex() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(name = "z",colours = colorRampPalette(c("dark green", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "purple", "blue"))(100), trans = "log")

print(p2)
```

Comment: Try adding the same limits to both scales, e.g. `limits = c(50, 450)`

Comment: Works perfect @stefan tnx! :D